# ASP.NET Core Web API deployed to IIS 404 Not Found - No candidates found for the request path '/'

Tags: rest, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been stuck with this for a while now. Tried all solutions I found but still no success.

I've tried modifying `Program.cs`, `web.config`, installed .NET Core bundle, .NET SDK, ... nothing helped.

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with a single controller. In this controller, I have a default `GET` action that returns 'All OK' string.

If I run my project in VS it opens a browser with All OK message:

[local All OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKOfQ.png)

Then I published the project to a folder and made an IIS application that points to this folder. Application pool is set to ".NET CLR Version - No managed code".

When I run the app from IIS (Browse to root) I get the 404 Not Found page. I configured logging for this app and this is what I get in it:

```
|12|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory|Registered model binder providers, in the following order: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BinderTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.HeaderModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FloatingPointTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.EnumTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DateTimeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ByteArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider 
|1|DEBUG|Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host|Hosting starting 
|13|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Loaded hosting startup assembly <MyWebAppName>Api 
|0|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. 
|0|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Hosting environment: Production 
|0|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Content root path: D:\<MYFOLDER>\<MyWebAppName>Api\ 
|2|DEBUG|Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host|Hosting started 
|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://<MY HOST NAME>/<MyWebAppName>/ - - 
|0|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware|Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed. 
|1000|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|No candidates found for the request path '/' 
|2|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request did not match any endpoints 
|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://<MY HOST NAME>/<MyWebAppName>/ - - - 404 - - 26.0768ms
```

If anyone can point me to the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Em

EDIT: additional information from failed request trace

[Request summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQjdd.png)

In request details there are a lot of HANDLER_PRECONDITION_NOT_MATCH and some MODULE_PRECONDITION_NOT_MATCH records  before these 2 Warnings. It's too long to post all here

Comment: So what's the url when you run locally and where the "all ok" is coming from?

Comment: Yes, run from Visual Studio

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - edited the description with info from failed request trace.

Comment: You can try to remove web dav module in web.config: `<modules><remove name="WebDAVModule" /></modules>`.

Comment: Doesn't help either...

Comment: OMG, it was such a stupid mistake: since I'm new to this I didn't know you have to put app Name in URL twice, once for app and second for controller. So from VS the correct URL is https://localhost:7133/<MYAPP> while on IIS it is https://<SERVER>/<MYAPP>/<MYAPP>.
Maybe someone else finds this helpful.